# SQL Server Stored Procedure to Send Email

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This is my first attempt at writing a stored procedure that emails someone. When trying to execute I get these errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure EmailTodaysErrors, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near '@MailServer'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure EmailTodaysErrors, Line 26
Must declare the scalar variable "@mailserver".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure EmailTodaysErrors, Line 33
Must declare the scalar variable "@Body".
```

The code that I am using which is causing this is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE EmailTodaysErrors 
@SenderName varchar(100),
@SenderAddress varchar(100),
@RecipientName varchar(100),
@RecipientAddress varchar(100),
@Subject varchar(200),
@Body varchar(8000)
@MailServer varchar(100) = 'localhost'
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @oMail int --Object reference
declare @resultcode int
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OACreate 'CDONTS.NewMail', @oMail OUT

if @resultcode = 0
BEGIN
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OASetProperty @oMail, 'RemoteHost',  @mailserver
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OASetProperty @oMail, 'FromName', @SenderName
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OASetProperty @oMail, 'FromAddress',  @SenderAddress
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OASetProperty @oMail, 'From', @SenderAddress
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OASetProperty @oMail, 'To', @RecipientAddress
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OASetProperty @oMail, 'Subject', @Subject
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OASetProperty @oMail, 'Body', @Body
EXEC @resultcode = sp_OAMethod @oMail, 'Send', NULL
EXEC sp_OADestroy @oMail
END

set nocount off
GO
```

Comment: Is this for a class? This procedure is... suboptimal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the `@body` line, which is throwing off your declarations.

Add it here:

```
@Body varchar(8000), -- HERE
@MailServer varchar(100) = 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't use sp_oa_family to send mail, there is already a built-in solution with SQL Server: [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx). Simply configure Database Mail properly on your server, then call [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx).

Comment: I tried this method as well but I get stuck when it says profile name is not valid

Comment: As I said, *configure* Database Mail first: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175951.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's a comma missing in your parameters :

```
@Body varchar(8000), ---- HERE
@MailServer varchar(100) = 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 0):

From my blog post, [*Create a Database Mail Configuration Using T-SQL Script*](http://www.freshcodehub.com/Article/43/create-a-database-mail-configuration-using-t-sql-script), published 05 Feb 2018:

> ```
> --Sending Test Mail
> EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
> @profile_name = 'TestProfile', 
> @recipients = 'To Email Here', 
> @copy_recipients ='CC Email Here',             --For CC Email if exists
> @blind_copy_recipients= 'BCC Email Here',      --For BCC Email if exists
> @subject = 'Mail Subject Here', 
> @body = 'Mail Body Here',
> @body_format='HTML',
> @importance ='HIGH',
> @file_attachments='C:\Test.pdf';               --For Attachments if exists
> ```